# Absent any verb, when can you use an adverb?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

> [dualism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dualism) = {mass noun}
>   1. The division of something **conceptually** into two opposed or contrasted aspects, or the state of being so divided

I know that definitions don't have to be written as complete grammatical sentences,
but while reading the above definition, I noticed no verbs.

1. So what does **conceptually** modify? Is this use right?

2. Does this instance offer any lessons in the big picture?

Comment: The one thing I notice is that "division" is an act of dividing, so you could also say "Conceptually dividing something into two opposed aspects...".

Comment: @ColleenV: That's true, but on the other hand, we say "conceptual division", not \*"conceptually division".

Comment: @ruakh I think there is something special about words that are both a process, and the result of that process. The conceptual division of work is OK, but so is the division of work conceptually.  The division can be conceptual or be done conceptually.  I don't really have a good way to explain it clearly, which is why I haven't attemped an answer, but I don't think this is as cut and dried as adjective versus adverb.

Comment: @ColleenV: I think I see what you mean, thanks. I'll be interested to see the explanation that someone comes up with . . .

Comment: Implementation is also this type of word - I tried explaining it here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49636/9161 but wasn't that happy with the result. Maybe I'll poke around EL&U and see if something similar has been asked there. @ruakh

Comment: I asked the question on EL&U: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/240271/80039 I was wrong to lump the implementation question in with this question. It looks like your question is related to 'peripheral modifiers' and while nouns describing actions/processes are commonly used with them, they aren't the only ones. The use is correct, but I have some reading to do about peripheral modifiers before I can say anything more than that.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for the update. I'll monitor it too.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What does conceptually modify? ...

In this case, the word *conceptually* modifies the word *division*. Rewritten another way, the phrase would read: *The **conceptual** division of something into two opposed...*

> 1. ... Is this use right?

This use is indeed correct grammatically (as is this sentence).

> 2. Does this instance offer any lessons...?

Definitions by their very nature *define* what something ***is***. This is the implied verb that you're missing. To take your example, each definition listed for the word ***dualism*** makes the statement "Dualism ***is defined*** as..."

Answer (score 0):

There are also adverbs that refer to the whole sentence, especially adverbs that determine the viewpoint. "Conceptionally" indicates that there need not be a clear division but we have the concept of such a division. Mostly these adverbs are called sentence adverbs.